# Custom colors for Desikan-Killiany atlas freesurfer regions

Tags: graphics, 3d, visualization, imaging, neuroscience

I wish to know the best way to get a brain image that shows specific values or colors for each of the 68 freesurfer Desikan-Killiany atlas regions (on the fsaverage template). My input would be just those 68 values.

Making a [custom freesurferLUT](http://freesurfer.net/fswiki/FsTutorial/AnatomicalROI) file and having freesurfer load it seems to be one method but is anything more direct? also, I'm wondering if it's easy to show border outlines and labels for the cortical regions?